# What is the best alogrithm to solve the following resource planning problem?

Tags: algorithm

I need to find the most suitable alogrithm for the following problem

Enviorenment has `actions` and `resources`, agent need to build action plan to get target resource

example

```
resources
apple x2
floor x2

money x5


actions
idle 
   consumes
      time x1


buy_pie
   consumes
       time x1
       money x3
   produces
       pie x1


sell_apple
   consumes
      apple x1
   produces
      money x0.5

make_pie
   consumes
      apple x1
      floor x1
      time x5
   produces
      pie x1

target get pie x2 with min time
```

possible plans

make_pie -> make_pie which takes time x10

sell_apple -> sell_apple -> buy_pie -> buy_pie which takes time x2, so the alogrithm should produce this plan

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use A* alogrithm

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.